# Java library for PDF page splitting

Tags: java, pdf

Is there a Java library for PDF **page** splitting (**not document**). The final purpose is to parse text from each of the splits separately.

As an example, let's say I want to cut every pdf page into 4 pieces vertically -- see illustration:

[image: Pdf page cut]

Comment: Two choices that I know of: FO and iText.   I don't know what "cutting" means, because you have to redefine the page template to have four columns and then rearrange the content.  I'm not sure that it's easy.

Comment: I think that for you want, you'd have to convert the PDF to an image format and then cut the image. I'd look for info in those separate tasks.

Comment: @madth3 That would be no problem, but would prevent easy text parsing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After clarifying you want to parse text, there is this iText sample [ExtractPageContentArea](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=279) or (*as mentioned by @ipavlic*) the [PDFTextStripperByArea](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFTextStripperByArea.html) class from the Apache Pdfbox project.

Comment: That would work. Thank you; I've edited my question to include the extra info and accepted your answer. Please also include http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFTextStripperByArea.html for other lost souls.